# nginx www to non-www https redirect

Tags: nginx

I am trying to route [www.intelehealth.org](http://www.intelehealth.org) to https://intelehealth.org however whenever I hit the url [www.intelehealth.org](http://www.intelehealth.org) it gives me

[image: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID]

My nginx conf is

```
server {

        root /var/www/wordpress;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name intelehealth.org;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
# Disables Favicon Logging & Errors
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# Disables Robots.txt Logging & Errors
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# Denies Access to Hidden Files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}
# Blocks PHP files in Upload Directory
location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
# Enable WordPress Permalinks Support (default .htaccess replacement)
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/intelehealth.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/intelehealth.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = intelehealth.org) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name intelehealth.org;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I have setup a cname record for [www.intelehealth.org](http://www.intelehealth.org)

[image: as per the following screenshot]

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Read the error message. Look at the certificate. And don't use an un-prefixed name as the canonical name for your site (but do provision it with a redirect to the canonical). And next time, please don't post pictures of text you can copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your certificate misses the DNS name `www.intelehealth.org`, it is only valid for `intelehealth.org`. Either recreate the certificate so it contains both domains, or create a new certificate for the other domain.